# Can't click on anything in Android SDK preview window

Tags: android, preview

I ran my application in the Android emulator and now I cannot click on anything in the preview window. I cannot drag any widgets onto the window as well. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the reason, but is there a reason you haven't upgraded Android Studio. I'm guessing you probably haven't updated your Android tools and SDKs either.

Comment: Its because im a noob. I think its happening because im copying the activity_.xml to the content_xml

Comment: You might as well start over from scratch, close the current project, and create a new project. And before you go too far, I'd suggest you view the videos from this Udacity Android course for very beginners (made by Google). https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud837/l-4027328704 (just be sure to click on the blue button to access the course materials for free, you'll still need to register to access it, but at least, it won't ask you for a credit card number if you press that blue button instead of the 30 day trial button)